# Getting a type error attempt to use datetime series with pd.date_range

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Any help would be appreciated:
I create 2 datetime columns:

```
inbound['TA_DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(inbound['TA_DATE_TIME'])
inbound['final_time'] = pd.to_datetime(inbound['final_time'])
```

I create a list of dataframes based on unique values of another column

```
listoftraindatedf =[]
listoftrainid = list(inbound['train_id'].unique())
for i in listoftrainid:
    listoftraindatedf.append(inbound[inbound['train_id']==i])
```

I am now attempting to use pd.date_range to have another column that will give me datetime within the bounds of the 2 columns equally distributed.

```
for i in listoftraindatedf:
    i['EVENT_DT']=pd.date_range(start=i['TA_DATE_TIME'],end=i['final_time'],periods=i.shape[0])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-a5f3a4e1826b> in <module>()
      1 for i in listoftraindatedf:
----> 2     i['EVENT_DT'] = pd.date_range(start=i['TA_DATE_TIME'],end=i['final_time'],periods=i.shape[0])

C:\Software\Anaconda3 x64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py in date_range(start, end, periods, freq, tz, normalize, name, closed, **kwargs)
   1005         normalize=normalize,
   1006         closed=closed,
-> 1007         **kwargs,
   1008     )
   1009     return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(dtarr, name=name)

C:\Software\Anaconda3 x64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py in _generate_range(cls, start, end, periods, freq, tz, normalize, ambiguous, nonexistent, closed)
    369 
    370         if start is not None:
--> 371             start = Timestamp(start)
    372 
    373         if end is not None:

pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.__new__()

pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_to_tsobject()

TypeError: Cannot convert input [0        2021-07-01 12:43:00
622      2021-07-01 12:43:00
632      2021-07-01 12:43:00
1036     2021-07-01 12:43:00
1142     2021-07-01 12:43:00
                 ...        
206011   2021-07-01 12:43:00
206509   2021-07-01 12:43:00
207375   2021-07-01 12:43:00
208797   2021-07-01 12:43:00
209185   2021-07-01 12:43:00
Name: TA_DATE_TIME, Length: 384, dtype: datetime64[ns]] of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Timestamp

​

Here is an example of the the date time series:
A_DATE_TIME final_time
0   2021-07-01 12:43:00 2021-07-01 20:43:00
622 2021-07-01 12:43:00 2021-07-01 20:43:00
632 2021-07-01 12:43:00 2021-07-01 20:43:00
1036    2021-07-01 12:43:00 2021-07-01 20:43:00
1142    2021-07-01 12:43:00 2021-07-01 20:43:00
```

The output I am looking for is a third column with a date time of evenly distributed datetimes covering the time period between these times

Comment: always provide a sample of your input data set, and a sample of what the output should look like, as well as paste the entire traceback of your error.  If you can edit your question to include these your changes of getting a good answer will increase significantly.

Comment: start and end parameters of the date range need to be Timestamp, not Series of them.